# What am I missing (first time Yarn user + JQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, yarnpkg

So I am simply attempting to add the JQuery runtime to a .NET Core website project using Yarn.

The command I run in the project folder is:

```
  yarn add jquery --modules-folder ./root/scripts
```

and it does indeed add jQuery (to the specified subfolder), but it adds WAY more than I expected it to. With Nuget I would have gotten:

```
  jquery-3.3.1.js
  jquery-3.3.1.min.js
  jquery-3.3.1.min.map
```

Even though Nuget would not have added the files as site content (though I could just xcopy them), I would have just what I need. But with Yarn, I get what appears to be an entire source repository:

[image]

with 123 files in total (and the files in dist aren't even tagged with a version number).

Is this the expected result... am I using Yarn wrong (conceptually)?

Am I supposed to be building JQuery as part of my project rather than just including and using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marko's description (and that awesome graph) gives a great explanation as to what is happening. To answer the question about resolving it, there are a dizzying array of potential options from Gulp to WebPack.

For something as simple as copying a couple of javascript libraries however, I'd suggest using the basic `BuildBundlerMinifier` that has been included with ASP.NET for quite some time.

The default ASP.NET Core 2.0 template includes partial support out of the box but you do need to make a couple of changes to your project to get things working:

1. In your `.csproj` file, you need to add a Package Reference for `BuildBundlerMinifier`. You'll add this to the same `<ItemGroup>` as the reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`. This will enable the bundler and cause it to fire off during build.

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
     <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.6.362" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. As I mentioned, the standard templates have  *partial* support for the bundler. By this I mean it includes a `bundleconfig.json` file in the root of your project by default. This file configures which files are touched by the bundler. If all you're looking for is `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` then your file should look something like this:

   ```json
   [
     {
       "outputFileName": "root/scripts/jquery.min.js",
       "inputFiles": [
         "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
       ],
       "minify": {
         "enabled": false
       }
     }
   ]
   ```

The net result here is that each time you build your project, the bundler will automatically copy `jquery.min.js` from `node_modules/jquery/dist/` to `root/scripts/`.

If you're using Yarn, I also highly recommend the [`Yarn.MSBuild`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Yarn.MSBuild/) library. This package enables MSBuild to automatically retrieve your Yarn packages during build. When combined with the bundler, this ensures you have an up-to-date copy of your packages in your `/scripts` folder each time you build.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I wasn't even aware of BuildBundleMinifier, but I just used it to one to one copy across the JQuery files from the Nuget package into my site which kept things lite.

Answer (score 2):

This is how `yarn`, or more accurately the `npm`, which `yarn` is using as the repository for modules, works.

It doesn't really install just the library. It installs the whole package that is published. Often, the publisher doesn't take the effort to omit some files in the published version and you basically get the whole repository. This includes the expected library files, along with documentation, the original source code, tests and so on.

This is why this image about `node_modules` is funny to people who had to use the `npm` at some point in their life:

[image]

To answer your question: no you're not using it wrong. It's working as intended, strange as it might seem.

If you want just the specific files, your best bet would be to use `yarn` to install, then copy the files over. But be careful, if you update the package versions, the destinations of your files might change, so keep that in mind.